# Как присоединить объект к анимации, что бы этот объект потом двигался за анимацией. Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

Я делаю платформер с большим количеством разного оружия, я хочу сделать анимацию взмаха рукой и потом к ней присоединить спрайт меча, можно ли в Unity2D сделать так, что бы потом меч двигался за анимацией.

Comment: Конечно же можно

Comment: Если можно, то как?